# How to integrate KendoUI chart with SignalR

Tags: kendo-ui, signalr, kendo-chart

i want to create a real time chart, using Kendo ui chart and signalr. I see this [example](http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/chart-api/benchmark), but has no code. So i try alone.

A little demonstration of my code:

At first I created a kendo chart

```
function queueActivityChart() {
    $("#queueActivityChart").kendoChart({
        legend: {
            visible: true
        },
        seriesDefaults: {
            labels: {
                visible: true,
                format: "{0}",
                background: "transparent"
            }
        },
        series: [{
            type: "line",
            field: "Incoming",
            categoryField: "DateTime",
        }],
        valueAxis: {
            labels: {
                format: "{0}"
            },
            line: {
                visible: false
            }
        },
        categoryAxis: {
            labels:
                {
                    rotation: -90,
                    dateFormats:
                        {
                            seconds: "ss",
                            minutes: "HH:mm:ss",
                            hours: "HH:mm",
                            days: "dd/MM",
                            months: "MMM 'yy",
                            years: "yyyy"
                        }
                }, type: "Date", field: "DateTime", baseUnit: "seconds"
        }

    });
    var chart = $("#queueActivityChart").data("kendoChart");
    chart.options.transitions = false;
}

$(document).ready(queueActivityChart);
$(document).bind("kendo:skinChange", queueActivityChart);
```

Then I have this part of code, that get from server data

```
    $scope.signalRData = [];
    $scope.signalR.on('receiveCounters', function (data) {
        $scope.queueData = data;
        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            $scope.signalRData.push(data[i]);
        }
        while ($scope.signalRData.length > 12) {
            $scope.signalRData.splice(0, 1);
        }
        $("#queueActivityChart").data("kendoChart").setDataSource(
            new kendo.data.DataSource({
                group: {
                    field: "Name"
                },
                data: $scope.signalRData
        }));
    });
```

This works! And I get a picture of the latest updated items.

But the problem is that this chart is like to put one picture in front of other. I mean that this is the **first time that load *Data Source***; that creates a chart of my data, *the second time my data has changed*, some values are still in my array some others has move out, the third too.

> It seems like it puts a picture of my current data in front of the
>   previous data. It's not *smoothie* and cannot use chart's legend
>   property because I initialize my Data Source everytime.

Can someone help me how can create a smoothie kendo chart with real time data like the kendo official example? Also can somehow to add scroller to bottom?

Comment: can you please explain what is smoothie here, a technical term or some slag ?

Answer (score 0):

I looked at the code for the benchmark and I think you may be missing in your chart which is `renderAs: "canvas"`

Also, in the example, the data is kept locally (saved) and then moved so it creates that "smooth" effect you may be talking about.

Here is the code that you can be of interest:

```
function step() {
    addPoint();
    $("#chart").data("kendoChart").refresh();
    frames++;
    if (playing) {
        kendo.animationFrame(step);
    }
}

function addPoint() {
    var stockData,
        change,
        lastValue;

    // Shift existing categories to the left and add the next date at the end
    lastDate = new Date(lastDate.getTime() + TICKS_PER_DAY);
    categoryList.push((lastDate.getMonth() + 1) + "/" + (lastDate.getDay() + 1));

    if (categoryList.length > POINTS) {
        categoryList.shift();
    }

    for (var i = 0; i < stocks.length; i++) {
        stockData = stocks[i];
        change = (Math.random() > 0.5 ? 1 : - 1) * Math.random() * 10;
        lastValue = stockData[stockData.length - 1] || Math.random() * 10;

        // Add a new pseudo-random data point
        stockData.push(Math.min((i + 1) * 20, Math.max((i + 1) * 10, lastValue + change)));

        // Shift the data points of each series to the left
        if (stockData.length > POINTS) {
            stockData.shift();
        }
    }
}
```

Check out the source code of your [example](http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/chart-api/benchmark) for the full source code and use the [dojo](http://dojo.telerik.com) to test our their code and play around with it easily

Comment: thank you for your response! but i cannot find anywhere source code of example :/

Comment: Right click on the page and click on view source